# Data binding in vue not updating

Tags: vue.js, data-binding

I have this code in two locations of a page (the post code needs to be displayed twice):

```
        <store-text-field
            :store_id="clonedStore.id"
            relation="address"
            field="post_code"
            @value-updated="postCodeUpdated"
            :value="clonedStore.address.post_code"/>
```

Within the component the `post_code` can be changed and the value passed back to the parent via the `value-updated` event.

The event code:

```
            postCodeUpdated(value) {
                console.log('post code updated to: ' + value)
                this.clonedStore.address.post_code = value;
            }
```

Every thing works fine, except the second component does not update with a new value if the `post_code` is changed in the other.

I expected the value to change as it is binded to `this.clonedStore.address.post_code` which is changed when the event is detected.

EDIT:

```
        data() {
            return {
                clonedStore: {
                    address: {
                        post_code: ''
                    }
                },
                showStoreNameInput: false,
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a Reactivity issue you need to use `$set` for setting value.

try this.

```
this.$set(this.clonedStore.address,'post_code',value)
```